# Is there a way to force the user to explicitly specify the template argument type?

Tags: c++, templates

Short version: I have a template function, which is "universal", but I want to force the user to explicitly specify the type of the argument, they pass as parameter to this function.

Any ideas?

---

Long version: sounds like a terrible design, but here's my case and I can't think of anything better at the moment.

I'm trying to "implement" `::setsockopt` in a small `socket` class (and I don't want to have tons of functions, taking different arguments and doing the same). For example:

```
template< typename OPTION_VALUE_TYPE >
bool set_option( int level, int option_name, const OPTION_VALUE_TYPE& value )
{
    return -1 != ::setsockopt( fd_, level, option_name, &value, sizeof( value ) );
}
```

BUT, this could lead to the following situation - invoking `set_option` with `1`, trying to set `unsigned char` option would lead to failure, as `1` is `int`. Correct usage would be:

```
set_option< unsigned char >( level, option, 1 );
```

as

```
set_option( level, option, 1 );
```

will compile perfectly fine, but will be terribly wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you just need to use the template parameter in a way from which it cannot be deduced from the arguments. A common way of doing that is using a typedef in a template class:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity {
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename OPTION_VALUE_TYPE>
bool set_option(int level, int option_name,
                typename identity<const OPTION_VALUE_TYPE&>::type value);
```

To use a type already present in the standard library, you could use `enable_if`:

```
template <typename OPTION_VALUE_TYPE>
bool set_option(int level, int option_name,
                typename std::enable_if<true, const OPTION_VALUE_TYPE&>::type value);
```

The reason this doesn't allow type argument deduction is because the compiler cannot rule out specialisations of `identity`: the compiler cannot rule out you doing

```
template <>
struct identity<U> { typedef V type; };
```

where `identity<U>::type` would no longer be `U`.

Comment: Other options from the standard library would be to use `typename add_const<T>::type&`  or `typename add_lvalue_reference<const T>::type`, which are probably a bit clearer. Using `enable_if` might confuse people into thinking there is some SFINAE involved.

Comment: @JonathanWakely That's a good point. On the other hand, using `add_const` or `add_lvalue_reference` doesn't make it clear that something special is going on, and could lead someone doing a code cleanup into thinking it could just be simplified by spelling out `const OPTION_VALUE_TYPE&`. I think there's something to be said for both, and I think the clearest approach is creating that `identity` helper class, and simply forgetting about the standard library types.

Comment: Yes, good point. `identity` serves no other purpose except to do this, so it's the most expressive solution.

Comment: What if I want the function to be `constexpr`?

Comment: @rr- Then just add `constexpr`? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I was pretty sure my GCC 5.2.0 complained about things when I tried it that way, but now that I tested it in clean environment, it works, so it had to be something different. Pardon.

Comment: For those who use C++ 20 or later, the standard library has provided [```std::type_identity```](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity)

Answer (score 4):

Put the template type in a non deduced context as in the following:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };

template <typename OPTION_VALUE_TYPE>
bool set_option(int level,
                int option_name,
                const typename identity<OPTION_VALUE_TYPE>::type& value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to force the user to explicitly pass a type parameter for calling a function `f` is like this. Say `f` is like:

```cpp
template <typename T> void f(T a) { cout << a + 5 << endl };
```

You rewrite it with an alias param to `T` like this:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename TT = T> void f(TT a) { cout << a + 5 << endl };
```

Now:

```
int main() {
  int a = 3;
  f<int>(a); // Instead the caller is forced to specify the type parameter
  // f(a); // This usage does not compile
}
```

---

For your specific function `set_option` you would need to rewrite it as:

```cpp
template<typename T, OPTION_VALUE_TYPE = T>
bool set_option(int level, int option_name, const T& value) {...}
```